# A lemma for a new proof for the existence of a rational between two arbitrary real numbers

Tags: calculus, proof-writing, induction, real-numbers

[image]I had in mind to prove the theorem "There exists a rational number between each two arbitrary Real numbers" and towards the end, I happened to need to prove this: $$$$
If we have the two numbers $b$ and $c$ ($b \neq c$), we can always create a number arbitrary close to say, $b$, using just $b$ and $c$. $$$$
Let us name $A_0 = \frac{b+c}{2}$.
We take the average of $A_0$ and b, call it something like $A_1$ and continue this process. It is clear that each $A_{n+1}$ is closer to b than $A_{n}$. $$$$
To formalize the concept I defined the following, inductively: $$$$
Let $f(x)$ be an arbitrary function:
We define $f_1(x)=f(x)$ and $f_n(x)=f_{n-1}(f(x))$ which is just a more detailewd writing of $f_n(x) = fofofo...of(x) $ n times $$$$
So, what we wish to prove now is this: If $b$ and $c$ are real numbers and $f(x)= \frac{b+x}{2}$, prove $$$$
$$\forall \epsilon>0 \hspace{0.5cm} \exists n (|f_n(c)-b|<\epsilon)$$
I'd be very thankful if someone provides a proof or a hint to the proof since this is of a very different form than the theorems I've seen before.

Comment: You can compute the distance explicitly.

Comment: Specifically, $f_n(x)=b+(x-b)/2^n$.

Comment: I don't see how this result helps in locating a rational between two reals. You will need some form of completeness here. The proof is trivial if reals have been constructed out of rationals.

Answer (score 1):

You have that $|f(x)-b|=\frac{|x-b|}{2}$ by the definition of $f(x)$. So by induction, $|f_{n}(x)-b|=\frac{|x-b|}{2^n}$. So in your last formula you just have to pick $n$ such that $\frac{|c-b|}{2^n}<\varepsilon$.

Comment: $f_n(x)$ is fofo....of(x), n times and not f to the power of n.

Comment: Okey, I changed the notation.